# How to Set indicator on view pager?

Tags: java, android, xml

i am trying to show the indicator on view pager such a way that indicator become in bottom of the image and align Center horizontal and center vertical I used Frame layout for this purpose but still not getting desired result.. i think i am missing any attribute my XML code is:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/baneer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="140dp"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/myfivepanelpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="130dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="#f6f7f9"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
                android:id="@+id/view_indicator"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this :
`android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` instead of `android:layout_gravity="bottom"`